# Problem with a wordpress admin system. and website

Tags: 404-error, server, apache

When i use wordpress i got random connection problem, and website is off for around 5 to 10 min. Wen i check error logs i got somethink like this: Any help?
[image: rd]

Comment: Are those real pages on your site? Are you saying that the site randomly stops working and then you find failures in the log? That might mean it's the PHP module that's fallen over, although in that case I'd expect a 500-series error code.

Comment: Yes, that real page set up on hosting, I can add that it was automatic install WordPress. About random problem, is when I user admin system of WordPress, the random stopping (they show error website message 504 or 404). So I contact hosting provider, and they say me that hosting is all right, and if they is any problem, that mean is problem with my connection, but that looks very abnormal to have problem for 5 min to connect just for this one page. So when I look on my logs I find this type of error, but I do not know what that mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of them either. Do you have non-WordPress pages on your site that you can test accessing when the site goes down? I really don't think this is a WordPress problem, though, unless your server is very low on resources and WordPress is somehow bringing it down. When it does crash can you try testing the server via another route, e.g. your phone, to see if it genuinely is a connection issue at your end or a server failure? Are there any server logs from the failure - is this a VPC, i.e. you control Apache, or a hosted environment where you don't?

Comment: I'm also nervous about the "HTTP/1.0" and "Apache SSL/TLS access". Almost nothing uses HTTP/1.0 anymore (and does HTTP/1.0 work OK with your site setup, i.e. is your site in a virtual host only, and not the default document path for when there's no Host header?) and I'd be surprised if anything used HTTP/1.0 over TLS. What do your logs look like when the site is working - are there any obvious differences e.g. the HTTP version?

Comment: Ok, I PlaskDesk(https://www.plesk.com/) on hosting, so what I understand I have full control over apache and all other stall, unlucky only limit i have is to be use only by WordPress, so a can open any other page. When a look on my phone, and as well other laptop, the website show with different error, On phone was error 504, on the other laptop error 404. The offers a have is ready to use WordPress with full control. About normal logs is like this: https://imgur.com/pcYnmis

Comment: Just happedn now, and this is a error message from pc, https://imgur.com/WDHcguC. On phone i have diffrend one, is code 404 this time. On otjer phone is Time out

Comment: Yes, it's timing out for me as well. It's also timing out for a request to /wp-content/ which should be served statically by Apache, and to your IP address so it's not a virtual host issue. So if this is a WordPress issue then it's because WordPress is tying up the server resources, e.g. memory, CPU, or Apache workers. I think you need to shell into the server and see if there are any processes which are hogging the CPU or memory (e.g. with top), or if the server has crashed (check the uptime? logs?) or something else.

Comment: Hmm, I try to login in to my serwer, but i got error as well, "Sorry, this page cannot be accessed at this time (Error 500)" so I cant check any logs, but if im not wrong, looks like is crashed

Comment: Is that the Plesk dashboard? That shouldn't happen, and you can ask support for help with that. I meant SSH into the server though.

Comment: Ye, i have problem to open Plesk dashboard, because i got as well the time out error. I ask support, and only information i got is that, this is not the problem with the serwer, and looks for them to be a connection problem.About Plask dashboard now is on, so i goona look for logs about uptime.

Comment: I cant find any report about up time. Did Plesk have this information?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Plesk. (I'd be very surprised if not, though.) If you SSH in then it's just `uptime`, if it's not already printed in the welcome message.

Comment: I find information about server usage, traffic and a lots other think, as well the server status (when working is online) if not working i dont have access to plask, but no information about uptime

Comment: Is possible that this problem with themes or plusgins? Or more like is just a completly problem with wordpress?

Comment: It could be, so it might be worth trying a standard theme and disabling all the plugins - except this is a production server, so you might want to clone the server (and database if separate) and experiment on that if you can still reproduce the problem there. But whilst it's possible WordPress is causing the problem, it's not clear to me what's actually going wrong. You're going to have to get more information from the server. I think the best way to do this is to log into the server using SSH and watch what's happening using `top` - is this a memory problem, swap, CPU, stuck process?

Comment: I don't know if Plesk are willing to help you with this or not. I don't know how thoroughly they looked when they said nothing was wrong: if they just gave it a glance when it was working fine, or if they did look thoroughly at the logs and decided there wasn't anything wrong. But if you tried to look at your Plesk dashboard and got a 500 error there then that's either a server problem or a bug in their software and they should be able to help you with that.

Comment: Well i contact support when i have problem, and what they is just that the server is all right and this is problem with my conncetion. But why i have problem to open Plesk, when plesk is just admin system software like CPanel, if i'm understand this right, when i don't have access to Plesk, that mean i dont have access to server. Only plugins, is just woocomerce, ACF, jetpack and adrotaion. I dont think any of then make a problem, but for theam i use blank free copyright temple, when i only add some html, css, js and php in temple file(dont touch function file).

Comment: I go look over weekend by SSH and change the temple, i hope this help. My biggest problem is that i dont know what make a problema and not sure where the problem is locate, what make super hard to find solution

Comment: Start with this, i test on normal temple and the problem stop show up (so its probably problem with temple, not sure how to sort out, its possible that i make some type of loop in temple that send many request to website, just by temple?) next what i find, all logs show its a server down (reboot himself), one of the hosting support people say its looks like a too many request is send from website. About SSH is do not show any other usefully information that that the server is reboot himself. Any idea how i made this type of error? This is not my first temple.